# Add a horizontal report in getorgchart for family tree support

Tags: orgchart, getorgchart

I'm using getorgchart to render a basic family tree, but I'm stuck at the point where I can't find a way to add a spouse (husband/wife), which would roughly map to a horizontal report in an organisational chart. Can anyone think of any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Get Org chart Documentation](http://www.getorgchart.com/Documentation), you have to add `layout` for your chart.

layout default value will be `null`

> `layout: getOrgChart.MIXED_HIERARCHY_RIGHT_LINKS,`

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/GetOrgChart/h221oc5b/2/)